# Elasticsearch поиск свойству не равно null

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch поиск по свойству, то что оно не равно null. Делаю так `.Query(s => s.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Exists(e => e.Field(f => f.fields.EventId.Id)))))` но в ответе нет документов.
Такие документы в самом elastic есть:`"fields": { "address": "https://0.0.0.0:81", "EventId": { "Id": 14,"Name": "ListeningOnAddress"},`.
Это лог Logger из приложения.
Сами классы для мапинга,cоздал через специальную вставку у Visual Studio
2022.

```
public class _Source
{
    [Date(Format = DateFormat.strict_date_hour_minute_second, Name = "@timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }    
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string messageTemplate { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }    
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string chargePoint { get; set; }      
    public Eventid EventId { get; set; }    
    public string SourceContext { get; set; }
    public string ActionId { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string RequestPath { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public object UserId { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
}

public class Eventid
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А запрос какой в логах отправляется, а ответ какой приходит?

Comment: @aepot возвращается пустая коллекция. А как посмотреть лог?

Comment: эластик логи умеет писать, насколько я помню

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось в мапинге, если не удалось серилизовать в объект c# то и поиска не будет. Нужно было добавить атрибуты

```
[Object]
[PropertyName("EventId")]
public Eventid EventId { get; set; }
```

и

```
[Number(NumberType.Integer, Name = "Id")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Text]
public string? Name { get; set; }
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/attribute-mapping.html)